# How to call a function periodically while my MainWindow is active?

Tags: python, pyqt5, multiprocessing

I have tried doing it with multiprocessing module to no avail. I get the following error:

*TypeError: cannot pickle 'MainWindow' object*

```
import time, multiprocessing
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initializeUI()
        self.show()


    def initializeUI(self):
        # UI stuff

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QGridLayout())

        dummy_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ok")
        self.layout().addWidget(dummy_btn)

        updater = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.update_function, args=[])
        updater.start()

    def update_function(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("This text, again!")
        self.update_function()



app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proper way to do this is to not use any sort of parallel mechanism, instead use `QTimer.singleshot`, as QT doesn't work well with multiprocessing or threading, and if you want to repeat it then you can just connect the function to a `Qtimer.timeout` signal and set the timer on repeat using `Qtimer.start()` [as in this tutorial](https://pythonpyqt.com/qtimer/)

```py
import time, multiprocessing
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initializeUI()
        self.show()


    def initializeUI(self):
        # UI stuff

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QGridLayout())

        dummy_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ok")
        self.layout().addWidget(dummy_btn)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        # self.timer.singleShot(2000,self.update_function)  # for one time call only
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_function)
        self.timer.start(2000) # time in milliseconds.

    def update_function(self):
        # time.sleep(2) this is not needed
        print("This text, again!")
        self.update()  # this had a typo



app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

**Edit:** to clarify on working with threads and multiprocessing, if you use multiprocessing for example there are many precautions, such as putting an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard on your code, and not use anything that belong to QT inside the subprocesses, and just use it for running things that don't need QT, like reading files and doing calculations.

as for threading, using any QWidget object in another thread other than your main application thread is going to crash your application, you can emit signals from child threads for signaling, but you cannot update the GUI on another thread, so only use QT objects that don't touch the GUI inside threads. (like networking, reading files, and sharing the CPU for extra calculations)

Comment: Single shot makes no sense here. You can use the interval functionality provided by QTimer. As the main window is the parent, the timer will be deleted automatically when the window is deleted.

Comment: The phrase "QT doesn't work well with multiprocessing or threading" is imprecise and misleading: Qt can work very well with both, PyQt/PySide may complicate or limit things at a certain level (for instance, the absence of full parallelism for threading), and obviously widgets are not thread safe, but "Qt" is not just about widgets, and there's plenty of Qt objects that are completely safe to use in threading.

Comment: @musicamante i'll clarify that part

Comment: @musicamante whenever i see QT and segmentation fault in the same sentence i always look for the word `thread` in code, and i always find it, so my warning makes sense.

Comment: @AhmedAEK The fact that similar questions are more commonly about this kind of issues doesn't mean that the problem is in "Qt not working well with...": some mistakes are just more common with inexperienced users of a certain system. As said, Qt works pretty fine with mp/mt, *as long as it's done correctly*, which is a mandatory requirement for the complexity and implications of those aspects. And your update is still imprecise about "things not related to Qt": you can perfectly work in other threads with Qt classes *that are thread-safe*, such as QProcess, QFile, QImage, QPainter, etc.

Comment: Pretty sure QPainter will cause a segmentation fault if it tries to modify the GUI, and the deletion of these objects sometimes result in segfaults as QT seems to forget that other threads have references to them, so i wouldn't recommend anyone to use them across threads